# How to return Async ActionResult of another controller's action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two controllers: A is derived from AsyncController, B is derived from Controller. A has DoAsync and DoCompleted methods. I need to return from action of B controller actionresult of action Do of A controller without redirect. If I try just return A.Do() from action in B controllers, null is returned. (I use T4MVC)

Comment: Can you post your controller logic?